# getting "2032 - EIF - CR char inside unquoted, not part of EOL @ pos" error with my perl script

Tags: perl, csv

I have  written a simple perl script to read a line from a .csv file. The code is as per below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 });


open my $fh, "<", "testresults.csv" or die "testresults.csv $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
      my @fields = @$row;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag;
close $fh or die "testresults.csv $!";
```

And the testresults.csv file looks like this:

**Node1,Node2,Node3,Node4,map1,map2,map3,map4,map5,map6,map7,map8,DM,LAT,AVG,product**

on the first line followed by the results on each line:

**name1,name2,name3,name4,Node1,Node2,Node3,Node4,Node5,Node6,Node7,Node8,0%,

0.002835480002,0.1714008533,4.86003691857886E-04**

and so on.

I am getting the following error with my code when I do a ./filename.pl from the command prompt:
    **CSV_XS ERROR: 2032 - EIF - CR char inside unquoted, not part of EOL @ pos 420**

I tried to google for this error but could not fathom much into this error.

Comment: Sounds like you have some characters hidden in your data where you don't expect them. Try `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;` and then try printing a few lines with `while(<$fh>) { print Dumper $_ }`. A fairly common issue is having Windows-type line endings.

Comment: @TLP: I think you have a very valid point. The testresults.csv was created by another VB script on a windows machine while I am running my perl script on linux. I will see if I can sort this out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. If you have a specific line ending, you can set it in the Text::CSV options with e.g. `eol => "\r\n"`

Comment: With     eol => $/ or      eol => "\r\n", the error persists.

Comment: Well, did you find any mysterious characters when you used `Data::Dumper`?

Comment: \0N\0o\0d\0e\0001\0 is shown instead of Node1, and so on

Comment: Now that's some fancy coding in that VB script. Strings with null characters. Unless you feel attached to them, you can try stripping them with `perl -i.bak -pwe 'tr/\0//d' testresults.csv` It will save a backup copy with `.bak` extension.

Comment: That looks very much like UTF-16BE (although you'd expect UTF-16LE on Windows).  You might want to look at [Text::CSV::Encoded](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV::Encoded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem from our conversation in the comments that the error comes of the strings in the input being interlaced with null characters, being made visible by using

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
while (<$fh>) {
    print Dumper $_;
}
```

A quick hack is to strip the null characters in the input file with something like:

```
perl -i.bak -pwe 'tr/\0//d' testresults.csv
```

**NOTE:** But as has been pointed out in comments from people more experienced in encoding matters, this can/could/should be solved by decoding your data instead. Just stripping the bad symbols might break your data in subtle ways, and is not an ideal solution.

I'm sorry, I do not know much about that, but using [Text::CSV::Encoded](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV%3a%3aEncoded) does sound like a good start, like cjm suggested.

Comment: You're welcome. Print in combination with Data::Dumper is an excellent debugging tool. Remember it until next time now!

Comment: -1 for teaching a hack without mentioning the downsides. A correct solution employs a proper decoding step.

Comment: @daxim Yes, I figured it might be wrong, that is why I said "The solution **may** be". I suppose that was too subtle.